Allow writer permissions for GitHub actions in private organization repository
I am the owner of a GitHub organization, and have created a private repository within the organization. I am setting up a GitHub action, but the action is failing because remote: Write access to repository not granted.
In the settings for the repository, I have selected read and write permissions:

However, when the action runs, only read permissions are turned on:

Is there something else I need to do in order to allow the action to have write permissions?
EDIT: Here is the workflow file:
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]
  workflow_dispatch:

name: bookdown

permissions: read-all

jobs:
  bookdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Only restrict concurrency for non-PR jobs
    concurrency:
      group: pkgdown-${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' || github.run_id }}
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-tinytex@v2
      
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-renv@v2

      - name: Cache bookdown results
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: _bookdown_files
          key: bookdown-${{ hashFiles('**/*Rmd') }}
          restore-keys: bookdown-

      - name: Build site
        run: source("_render.R")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Deploy book 
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4.5.0
        with:
          branch: deploy
          folder: _book


Could you share in your question how you configure the github workflow (yaml file) so that we can reproduce the issue please?

My guess is that it might be related to not configuring the permissions: contents: write for the token permission in the workflow setup. As you might have given the token the permission in the org, but you may not have allow it to use them in the specific workflow.

@GuiFalourd I edited the question to include the workflow file.

Your issue is related to the permissions: read-all in the setup. This will overwrite what your configured outside the run. Update the permissions according to the operations you'll perform using the token in your workflow (for example, with write-all).
